# Highcharts: automatically give a highlite backgroundcolor to one series item like in the hover state

Tags: charts, highcharts, state, series

I have a line/area chart in highcharts. When you hover over the chart you will see the tooltip but also a background color for that particular x-axis item. What I would love to have is this backgroundcolor automatically shown (without tooltip) (for the current month)without having to hover. So it makes the chart more easy to read and they can see directly what month it is.

[image]

Comment: Just use [`plotBands`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.plotBands).

Comment: thnx allot m8, diddn't know it was a plotband. great <3